# Compare 2 Columns to determine numbers that haven't matched up

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I have a web application that records the score of sports teams in a MySQL table called history.

```
id | winning_team | losing_team  | winning_score | losing_score
1  |     1        |      2       |      5        |      4
2  |     3        |      4       |      2        |      1
3  |     5        |      6       |      7        |      2
4  |     7        |      8       |      5        |      3
5  |     1        |      3       |      6        |      1
```

What I need to accomplish is to show the games that have not been played. For example I can see that team 1 has played team 2 and has played team 3, but I cant figure out the code to show that team 1 has NOT played teams 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. Using the following code I can get the games that have been played to display.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM history";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        echo "Team " . $row->winning_team;
        echo " has played";
        echo " team ". $row->losing_team;
        echo "<br>";
}
```

Here is what I have tried in order to get the teams that have not played, but to no success

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++) {
            if ($row->winning_team != $i){
                echo "Team " . $row->winning_team;
                echo " has NOT played";
                echo " team ". $i;
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
}
```

EDIT

```
id | winning_team | losing_team  | winning_score | losing_score | round
1  |     1        |      2       |      5        |      4       |   2
2  |     3        |      4       |      2        |      1       |   2
3  |     5        |      6       |      7        |      2       |   2
4  |     7        |      8       |      5        |      3       |   2
5  |     1        |      3       |      6        |      1       |   2
```

So if the table included a round column, I was hoping to SELECT * FROM history, and then have php handle everything based on the rounds. Im not sure if this is possible using a MySQL IF statement? Since round 1 is over there would be no need to show unplayed games from that round so I guess the questions becomes: Is there a query similar to the one posted that would only select rows where the round is the highest number? Once round 2 is finished, it would become round 3 so I don't necessarily want to hardcode 2 into the query

Answer (score 0):

There is a really nice function in MySQL called group_concat which is very handy in such case.
The function can concatenate the values (in your case we will take the `losing_team`) base on the grouped value (in your case - the `winning_team`).

```
SELECT winning_team, group_concat(losing_team) AS losing_team_str FROM history GROUP BY winning_team;
```

The output of this will be something like that:

```
winning_team | losing_team_str
    1        |      2,3     
    3        |      4     
    5        |      6     
    7        |      8
```

Now - in case you know ahead the ids of all your groups, you can use the `explode` function on the value of `losing_team_str`, and then `array_diff` to check which ids don't exists in your list:

```
$known_teams = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

$query = "SELECT winning_team, group_concat(losing_team) AS losing_team_str FROM history GROUP BY winning_team";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $loosing_teams = explode(",", $row->losing_team_str)
    $not_played_teams = array_diff($known_teams, $loosing_teams);

    echo "Team ". $row->winning_team ." \n";
    echo "hasn't played with teams: " . implode(", ", $not_played_teams) ."<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It works exactly how it should. However there is more. I was expecting to SELECT * FROM history and handle this in PHP and not use a MySQL function for the following reason. The teams play each other in rounds, much like a round robin. So for example the table would look like so.

Comment: You can add `WHERE \`round\` = 1` (or whichever round you want) to the query, for example.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. This almost solves the issue. Is there anyway to accomplish this in php by SELECT * FROM history; command with MySQL

Comment: Sure there is, you can do all the comparison/data-saving in php, however I really don't understand why would you do that

Comment: You're right, it is better to do it in SQL however I am more experienced in php. Ok say we do it your way...what if team 1 has not won a game yet. The query will not return them as a winning team, even though they have played x number of game and have x number of games remaining.

Comment: Well, if you have a table with all of your teams you can use that table with left join and it will solve your problem :)

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response...If I left join the ID of the player to the ID of the winning team, it simply just adds a new column with that played ID, and it still doesn't show the players who havent played any games

'SELECT profile.id, history.winning_team, group_concat(history.losing_team) AS losing_team_str FROM history LEFT JOIN profile ON profile.id=history.winning_team WHERE round = 2 GROUP BY winning_team'

Comment: Apologies...
`SELECT profile.id, history.winning_team, group_concat(history.losing_team) AS losing_team_str FROM history LEFT JOIN profile ON profile.id=history.winning_team WHERE round = 2 GROUP BY winning_team`

Comment: If you use `WHERE round = 2` you "override" the `left join` you have. You should have something like that: `SELECT profile.id, history.winning_team, group_concat(history.losing_team) AS losing_team_str FROM profile LEFT JOIN history ON (profile.id=history.winning_team AND history.round = 2) GROUP BY winning_team`